# deleting Blob from SQLiteCipher db

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am storing images in SQLiteCipher as a blob (byte[] form):

```
    public void insertNewImageBlob (byte[] image, String password) {
        System.out.println(image);
        SQLiteDatabase db = instance.getWritableDatabase(password);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_IMAGE, image);
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
        db.close();
    }
```

The table has nothing just a list of byte array, no ids or anything. Insertion is good, RecyclerView shows all the images from the database, now then the user clicks on the image, i want the one to be deleted. So, user clicks an image and I send the image to **deleteImage** method to delete it from the database.

Here is the code trying me to Delete a single image:

```
    public void deleteImage (String password, byte[] image) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = instance.getWritableDatabase(password);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_IMAGE,image);
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_IMAGE+"='"+ image +"'",null);
        db.close();
    }
```

But it does not delete the image from the database.

Comment: There is always id in SQLite's table - the one that you create as integer pk or automatic ROWID column

Comment: "The table has nothing just a list of byte array, no ids or anything" -- then add a primary key and delete by using the primary key.

Comment: The other method which may works is to use `SQLiteStatement` ... but seriously: you should not use blob as "where arg"

Comment: Thank you for answers, how could i access automatic ROWID column number ?

Comment: when you use `SQLiteDatabase.query` you should pass `new String { "ROWID", COLUMN_IMAGE }` as columns parameter ... then you may use `cursor.getLong(0)` for id  and `cursor.getBlob(1)` for image ... then you can use delte like `db.delete(TABLE_N, "ROWID=?, new String { String.valueOf(id) })`

Comment: Thank you Selvin so much! Gonna try and implement this. If not, going to add PK to every image and delete by PK instead of blob.

Comment: also remeber if image is large you will not get whole image with simple `SQLiteDatabase.query` as there is a CusorWindow limit (solution is easy to find with googling)